# Zend Framework - Dojo form support

Tags: zend-framework, forms, dojo, element, rangeslider

Hello i am new in Zend Framework
i have found that zend have support for dojo forms - Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_*
works pretty well.

But there are mising some elemnt like (BusyButton, RangeSlider or PasswordValidation)
Is zend support them??

I have found that Zend supports BusyButton (http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9641)
But i dont know how to use it?

Also i have found that zend contains this dojo elmements here:
ZendFramework/externals/dojo/dojox/form/

Would anybody be so kind and write me, some example how to use 
this form elements (BusyButton, RangeSlider or PasswordValidation) please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Dijits as described in the Zend Framework Manual.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.dojo.view.html